# Draw arrow with text inside

Tags: arrows

Is there a way to draw an arrow which has text inside, like the one in [image: this] image? I saw many examples with the `TikZ` but most of them had the text over the arrow not inside it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (-5,0);
  \coordinate (B) at ( 5,0);
  \draw[->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,fill=white] {\emph{success}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This, which does the same, may be more understandable to other users

```
\draw[->] (A) -- node[midway,fill=white] {\emph{success}} (B);
```

Comment: Mmm… second time TeX.SX asks me if I'm a robot. I don't know what to think.

Comment: It must have realized: you're an _answering machine_!

Comment: @PaulGessler I will change my name to distract them, I hope they don't notice. Or may be just chaning the image would do?

Comment: @Manuel: And if I want to draw more arrows do I just have more `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @Jessy09 More arrows in what sense? You just need to add as many `\draw[->] .. ;` code inside the same `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @Manuel: More arrows meaning one under the other. I tried it like you said and it works (I just have to modify the coordinates). Thank you again.

Comment: @Jessy09 If you are using diagrams you might want to look at `tikz-cd` documentation.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this without tikz and without any complicated code. The knowledge of TeX primitives is sufficient.

```
\def\arrowtext#1#2{\hbox to#1{\arrowtextA\ #2 \arrowtextA\kern2pt\llap{$\succ$}}}
\def\arrowtextA{\leaders\vrule height2.7pt depth-2.3pt\hfil}

\arrowtext{5cm}{success}
```

[image: success]

Edit: In response on the comment by @fpast below I show the example of diagonal arros with the middle text. The pdfTeX is supposed.

```
\def\arrowtext#1#2{\hbox to#1{\arrowtextA\ #2 \arrowtextA\kern2pt\llap{$\succ$}}}
\def\arrowtextA{\leaders\vrule height2.7pt depth-2.3pt\hfil}
\def\diagonal{\pdfsave\pdfsetmatrix{.7071 .7071 -.7071 .7071}}

\arrowtext{5cm}{success}

\vskip2cm \noindent
\diagonal\rlap{\arrowtext{3cm}{diagonal}}\pdfrestore
```

[image: success2]

Comment: Nice answer! However TeX primitives would not be enough if the arrow is not horizontal, I suppose

Comment: @fpast You can use `\special` primitive or pdfTeX primitive `\pdfsetmatrix` for setting the linear transformation.

Comment: Could you show us an example of a diagonal arrow, with text inside, drawn with these primitives?

Comment: @fpast OK, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I see. Impressive! Personally, I consider this code as more complicated than the Tikz/Metapost solutions above, but it is certainly due to the fact I don't know anything at all about all these primitives. It seems they are worth the learning!

Answer (score 9):

A solution with TikZ without filling the background with white:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (-2,0);
    \coordinate (B) at ( 2,0);
    \path (A) -- node (success) {\emph{success}} (B);
    \draw[->] (A) -- (success) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With library `calc`, the position of the node can also be calculated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (-2,0);
    \coordinate (B) at ( 2,0);
    \draw[->]
      ($(A)!.5!(B)$) node (success) {\emph{success}}
      (A) -- (success) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Remark:**

- The space between the arrow lines and the text is controlled by the inner margin of the node, set by option `inner sep`; default is `0.3333em`.

Comment: Very interesting solution. Unfortunately it work only for horizontal lines.

Answer (score 8):

Not too difficult to produce with MetaPost. The `draw arrow_withtext` macro I defined below produces an arrow with text placed precisely in the middle of the shaft, so that it can always be read from left to right (unless the shaft is vertical, of course :-))

```
input latexmp; setupLaTeXMP(textextlabel = enable, mode = rerun);

vardef drawarrow_withtext(expr A, B, str) =
  save mylabel, mid; 
  pair mid; mid = 0.5[A, B];
  picture mylabel; mylabel = thelabel(str, mid) 
    rotatedaround (mid, if xpart(B-A) >= 0: angle(B-A) else: angle(A-B) fi);
  drawarrow A -- B; unfill bbox mylabel; draw mylabel;
enddef;

beginfig(1); drawarrow_withtext(origin, 6cm*right, "success"); endfig;

beginfig(2); drawarrow_withtext(origin, 6cm*dir60, "success"); endfig;

beginfig(3); drawarrow_withtext(origin, 6cm*dir150, "success"); endfig;

end.
```

To be compiled with MetaPost and LaTeX as TeX engine: `mpost --tex=latex myfile.mp`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice! I had never used MetaPost. How to use your code with a normal `tex` file to insert the arrow in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: @Sigur See this topic: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142587/using-metapost-inline-in-latex-no-context?rq=1 for how to integrate MetaPost code into LaTeX code. I recommend the `gmp` package for LaTeX and PDFLaTeX and the `luamplib` package for LuaLaTeX (the most direct solution). Otherwise you can integrate the MetaPost drawings as external figures: see this very good introduction: http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpintro.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Based on Heiko Oberdiek solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1em]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (-2,-1);
    \coordinate (B) at ( 2,+1);
% invisible line, for sloped option:
\path (A) to node[sloped] (success) {\emph{success}} (B);
% real line with sloped text in the midle
\draw[->] (A) -- (success) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This lines can bi directed to any direction.